# Filling empty spaces in a CSV file

Tags: linux, awk

I have a CSV file where some columns are empty such as

```
oski14,safe,0,13,53,4
oski15,Unknow,,,,0
oski16,Unknow,,,,0
oski17,Unknow,,,,0
oski18,unsafe,0.55,,1,2
oski19,unsafe,0.12,4,,56
```

How do I replace all the empty columns with the word "empty".
I have tried using awk(which is a command I am learning to use).

I want to have

```
oski14,safe,0,13,53,4
oski15,Unknow,empty,empty,empty,0
oski16,Unknow,empty,empty,empty,0
oski17,Unknow,empty,empty,empty,0
oski18,unsafe,0.55,empty,1,2
oski19,unsafe,0.12,4,empty,56
```

I tried to replace just the 3rd column to see if I was on the right track

```
    awk -F '[[:space:]]' '$2 && !$3{$3="empty"}1' file
```

this left me with

```
oski14,safe,0,13,53,4
oski15,Unknow,,,,0
oski16,Unknow,,,,0
oski17,Unknow,,,,0
oski18,unsafe,0.55,,1,2
oski19,unsafe,0.12,4,,56
```

I have also tried

```
    nawk -F, '{$3="\ "?"empty":$3;print}' OFS="," file
```

this resulted in

```
oski14,safe,empty,13,53,4
oski15,Unknow,empty,,,0
oski16,Unknow,empty,,,0
oski17,Unknow,empty,,,0
oski18,unsafe,empty,,1,2
oski19,unsafe,empty,4,,56
```

Lastly I tried

```
    awk '{if (!$3) {print $1,$2,"empty"} else {print $1,$2,$3}}' file
```

this left me with

```
oski14,safe,empty,13,53,4 empty
oski15,Unknow,empty,,,0 empty
oski16,Unknow,empty,,,0 empty
oski17,Unknow,empty,,,0 empty
oski18,unsafe,empty,,1,2 empty
oski19,unsafe,empty,4,,56 empty
```

Comment: Add the (wrong) commands you tried to your post, so we can help you fixing them! Any regular expression of "^," (empty start) or ",," or ",$" (empty end) should allow you to insert your text (with replace)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a sed that supports EREs with a `-E` argument (e.g. GNU sed or OSX/BSD sed):

```
$ sed -E 's/(^|,)(,|$)/\1empty\2/g; s/(^|,)(,|$)/\1empty\2/g' file
oski14,safe,0,13,53,4
oski15,Unknow,empty,empty,empty,0
oski16,Unknow,empty,empty,empty,0
oski17,Unknow,empty,empty,empty,0
oski18,unsafe,0.55,empty,1,2
oski19,unsafe,0.12,4,empty,56
```

You need to do the substitution twice because given contiguous commas like `,,,` one regexp match would use up the first 2 `,`s and so you'd be left with `,empty,,`.

The above would change a completely empty line into `empty`, let us know if that's an issue.

Comment: @EdMorton, one side question (maybe opinion-based): `sed` does not have anything like `vim`'s `\ze` (and co.); is this "just" because `sed` only reads the file one-way-and-never-look-back?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis I don't know what that is in vim so idk if sed has it or not, sorry. I just use sed for simple `s/old/new` on individual strings, as in this case, and use awk for anything more interesting so even if I did know what that vim command does I probably wouldn't know if sed had something similar. See if a user named [@potong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/967492/potong) is around - he posts a lot of (to me) exotic sed answers and seems familiar with many of its arcane corners.

Answer (score 1):

This is the `awk` command

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=","; OFS="," }; { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ($i == "") { $i = "empty" }}; print $0 }' yourfile
```

As suggested in the comments, you can shorten the `BEGIN` procedure to `FS=OFS=","` as `awk` allows chained assignment (which I did not know, thank you @EdMorton).

I've set `FS=","` in the `BEGIN` procedure instead of using the `-F,` option just for uniformity with setting `OFS=","`.

Clearly you can put the script in a more nice looking form:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
  FS  = ","
  OFS = ","
}
{
  for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i)
    if ($i == "")
      $i = "empty"
  print $0
}
```

and use it as a standalone program (you have to `chmod +x` it), even if this is known to have some drawbacks (consult the comments to this question as well as [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/563456/164309)):

```
./the_script_above your_file
```

or

```
down_the_pipe | ./the_script_above | further_processing
```

Clearly you are still able to feed the above script to `awk` this way:

```
awk -f the_script_above file1 file2
```

Comment: FWIW `FS=OFS=","` saves hard-coding the `;` twice. nbd of course. You also don't need so many semi-colons and you can idiomatically use `1` instead of typing out `print $0` so the script could be a bit more concisely written as `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i == "") $i = "empty"} 1' yourfile`

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using a shebang nor redirecting input though as in your latest update. The former robs you of the ability to separate shell args into shell variables, awk variables, and awk file names (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/563456/133219) while the latter robs you of the ability to access the input file name with `FILENAME` and doesn't work at all when you have 2 or more input files.

Comment: @EdMorton, thank you for helping me improve my answer. I've not included anything about the `FILENAME` issue in my answer, as I think that that is relevant or not depending on the specific application; as in, if the file is coming down a pipe it's normal it has no name, isn't it?

Comment: Right, if the input is coming from a pipe then FILENAME is `-` but if it's NOT coming from a pipe then `FILENAME` contains the name of the file and that is frequently useful. So what I'm saying is that when input isn't coming from a pipe (as in this case), don't take away the ability for awk to populate FILENAME as something useful even if you don't use FILENAME right now in this script. There's 2 extremely common cases (`1)` you need to use FILENAME and `2)` you have multiple input files) that simply do not work if you do `awk 'script' < file` so just never do it.