# Why does vim consume the pattern after \ze in this case?

Tags: regex, vim, regex-lookarounds

Fyi, this question originated from [this `sed` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60030177/5825294).

Given a 5 columns CSV line with all 5 columns empty, i.e. a line which only contains `,,,,`, I thought the following `vim`-`ex` command should insert `hello` in all 5 positions:

```
:s/\v(^|,)\ze(,|$)/\1hello/g
```

However it does not, as the output is

```
hello,,hello,hello,hello
```

The first `hello` is inserted because `^\ze,` matches at the beginning of line. However it seems that this `,` is consumed by the command. Is this the case? If so, why?

Comment: No idea why, but `:%s/\v(^|,)@<=(,|$)@=/hello/g` works to only insert the first 4 positions, but you may run it twice to do the job.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew as you can see from the answer I linked, avoiding running the command twice is precisely the reason why I've asked this question.

Comment: Yeah, there is a problem with everything other than shorthands when matching a zero-length string at the end of a line, only things like `:%s/\_w*/hello/g` work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of the answer, but I can share a hunch.  I think this boils down to entirely zero-width match/replace patterns (e.g. `/^\ze,`) having to move some ethereal match index by one, even if it technically hasn't consumed anything.  That way it can still go to some next match, or else it will just keep matching in the same position (if that makes sense).

Your example seems to evidence of that.  A more illustrative example would be the following (changing the input to better show what was matched).

Given the following command:

```
:s/\v(^|.)\ze(.|$)/<0\11\22>/g
```

Running it against an input line of `abcd` will output:

```
<01a2>a<0b1c2><0c1d2><0d12>
```

Note how the `a` is both matched/replaced (in `<01a2>`), and is also *unmatched* as shown by the `a` in `<01a2>a<0b1c2>`.  This prevents the `ab` pair from being matched/replaced.

The only thing I can think of that would explain this is that idea of some match cursor or match index having to move past the first character of `a` after being matched by the first zero-width pattern of `/^\ze.`

In other words:

```
Input: abcd
Command: s/\v(^|.)\ze(.|$)/<0\11\22>/g
======================================

Match/Replace 1:
abcd => <01a2>abcd
^              ^

Matches /^ze.
Will move cursor by 1 after the zero-width /^\ze. match (or else it would be stuck there)

----------------

Match/Replace 2:
<01a2>abcd  =>  <01a2>a<0b1c2>cd
       ^                      ^

Matches /.\ze.
Consumes the '.' (in this case 'b').  Not entirely zero-width.

... and so on ...
```

Comment: So your point is that the only way the algorithm can go forward without getting stuck, is that it always consumes something non-zero width. Since the first match is `^\ze,`, and it is zero width, the engine will forcibly consume the `,` to go past the beginning. Right?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis Yep.  "Consumes something non-zero width" in this case being just move one forward.  That's my best guess to this at least.

Comment: At the moment this seems to be the best answer; accepted.